# forecasting python subtracting previous value and then converting back to original scale

Tags: python, forecasting

I have a forecasting problem and I am using 2 historical values to predict next 3 y values
and also transforming y by taking diff with previous value to make the series stationary

then

if my original y is                      `1, 3, 7, 12, 18`

then transformed y would be              `na, 2, 4, 5, 6`

If my model predicts                     `na, na, 5, 2 , 2`

then how do I convert them to original scale?
would it be                               `na, na, 8, 10, 12?`

I got 8 by adding original 3 to 5 from prediction, 10 by adding 2 from prediction to previous 8  ad 12 by adding 2 from prediction 10

Comment: why and how do you transform to `na, 2, 4, 5, 6`?  Can't you work with original values ?

Comment: if you trasform using `-` (minus) then you should transform it back using the same method but with `+`. Problem makes only `na`. You would have to set some default value. For `na, 2, 4, 5, 6` you can reacteate original values using `1, 1+2, 1+2+4, 1+2+4+5, 1+2+4+5+6` (it can mean cumulative sum `cumsum()`)